# String manipulation using PHP?

Tags: php, string, algorithm, json

How can I most efficiently, inject string `$A` in between every two commas in String `$B` that lie between reverse brackets.

```
$B = '},,,,,{'
```

transformed into into

```
$B = "},$A,$A,$A,$A,{"
```

I have thought of an algorythm that would find the specific pattern `'},,` count the amount of commas then replace it with the proper string. Though I was hoping there would be a more efficient way to do this, maybe with preg_replace?

Thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with JSON?

Comment: Google Doc's malformed JSON looks like that, instead of giving you empty values, it gives you commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use eval capabilities of preg_replace:

**e** (`PREG_REPLACE_EVAL`) - If this modifier is set, preg_replace() does normal substitution of backreferences in the replacement string, evaluates it as PHP code

```
# first we isolate }...{ and forward it to replace()
print preg_replace('/(}[^{]+{)/e', 'replace("$1","'.$A.'");', $B);

# next we replace ,, with ,$A,
function replace($x,$y) {
    return preg_replace("/,(?=,)/",",$y", $x);
}
```

or in short:

```
print preg_replace('/(}[^{]+{)/e', 'preg_replace("/,(?=,)/",",'.$A.'", "$1")', $B);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this perhaps? It might throw up over the fact it's an off number of commas though:

```
$B = '},,,,,{';

$C = str_replace(",,", ",$A", $B);
```

Unless you mean the literal string `$A`. Do let us know.

Comment: If I use the above code technique you represented. I would get `},$A,$A,{` giving me only two $A, when I want one between every two commas, that is I need four $A for the provided example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just replace every occurrence of a comma pattern with `$A`?

Like every two consecutive commas.

Comment: If I use the above code technique you represented. I would get `},$A,$A,{` giving me only two $A, when I want one between every two commas, that is I need four $A for the provided example.

Comment: No code in my answer means "work the fine details as required" ;)

Comment: I hinted at the end of the question that I was wondering if preg_replace gave me the option to count the amount of replacements needed then replace accordingly. To avoid any kind of looping algorithm.